# Deployment step 'ManualApprovalStep(...)' is not supported for CodePipeline-backed pipelines

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

we are trying to migrate from the v1 CdkPipeline to the v2 CodePipelin. In v1 there was this `manualApproval` attribute, which one had to set to true and then you had the manual approval after the changeset creation. This doesn't seem to exist anymore, so I tried to follow the [new way](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html#validation) but for some unknown reason I get this error when trying to create a cdk diff:

```
Deployment step 'ManualApprovalStep(ChangeSet Approval)' is not supported for CodePipeline-backed pipelines
```

This is the actual code:

```js
    const jfrogSsm = StringParameter.fromSecureStringParameterAttributes(this, 'ssm', {
      parameterName: '/some-key',
      version: 1,
    });
    const additionalPermissions = new PolicyStatement();
    additionalPermissions.addActions('ssm:GetParameters');
    additionalPermissions.addResources(ssm.parameterArn);

    const pipeline = new OrgCodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
      pipelineName: 'pipeline',
      stage: 'prd',
      github: {
        repo: 'repo-name',
        branch: 'master',
      },
      synthAction: {
        subdirectory: 'infrastructure',
        jfrogApiKey: {
          type: BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PARAMETER_STORE,
          value: jfrogSsm.parameterName,
        },
        buildCommand: 'npx run build',
        rolePolicyStatements: [additionalPermissions],
      },
    });


pipeline.addStage(new MyStage(this, 'MyInfra'), {
  pre: [new ManualApprovalStep('ManualApproval')],
});

pipeline.attachSlackHook({
  emoji: ':frog:',
  mention: '@team-name',
});
```

`attachSlackHook`: creates a Notification Lambda which sends a message to slack and is connected to the `onStateChange` method of the aws-codepipeline inside of cdks pipeline. To accomplish this in v2 we needed to have it as an additional call at the end because we need to call `buildPipeline` first to access the internal aws-codepipeline inside.

we have an internal construct library, which sets some defaults (called OrgCodePipeline here), which is constructed like this:

```js
export class OrgCodePipeline extends Construct {
  public readonly pipelineName: string;
  public readonly pipeline: CodePipeline;
  private readonly stage: string;

  public constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: OrgCodePipelineProps) {
    super(scope, id);

    this.pipelineName = props.pipelineName;
    this.stage = props.stage;

    const commands = createCommands(
      props.stage,
      props.synthAction.subdirectory,
      props.synthAction.synthCommand,
      props.synthAction.buildCommand,
    );

    const input = this.createCodeStarConnection(props.github);

    const synth = new CodeBuildStep('Synth', {
      installCommands: createInstallCommand(props.synthAction.synthType),
      commands,
      input,
      env: {
        JFROG_API_KEY: props.synthAction.jfrogApiKey.value,
      },
      rolePolicyStatements: props.synthAction.rolePolicyStatements,
      primaryOutputDirectory: 'cdk.out',
      buildEnvironment: {
        buildImage: LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_5_0,
      },
    });

    this.pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, id, {
      pipelineName: props.pipelineName,
      crossAccountKeys: false,
      synth,
    });
  }
```

`createCommands`: takes all the commands and concatenates them. In v1 they were splitted between synth and build commands.

`createCodeStarConnection`: creates a `CfnConnection` for the given repo and branch inside of our github org and returns the `CodePipelineSource`.

`createInstallCommand`: creates the install command for eithe npm or yarn. Also makes sure that our private jfrog artifactory is used

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What's `OrgCodePipeline`? What does its `addStage` do?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right ManualApprovalStep? Code suggests it should work 
-- https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/dcc9e59d55d17dd71217659573d5f1879295eb1b/packages/%40aws-cdk/pipelines/lib/codepipeline/codepipeline.ts#L524-L537

Comment: @kichik they're calling `addStage` on their own custom class, not `pipelines.CodePipeline`, so who knows what their implementation is.

Comment: it just forwards the call to the real CodePipelines addStage function, so you don't need to call pipeline.pipeline.addStage(). This is the implementation: 

``` 
public addStage(stage: Stage, options?: AddStageOpts): StageDeployment {
    return this.pipeline.addStage(stage, options);
  }
```
and both ways give the same error